# get the value of each check marked check box inside rad grid in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, telerik-grid

In my radgrid I am using check box to select the required values from the multiple options. In my code behind, I want to get the value of every checked rows. But my loop is not working.

*Also I am not sure whether I am using the correct approach for the checkbox inside rad grid. Please suggest*.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rg_get_profession" runat="server"
PageSize="100"
AllowSorting="true"
Width="100%"
AllowPaging="True"
ShowGroupPanel="false"
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
GridLines="Both"
HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="false" ShowFooter="false">
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TempCol1" HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="p_id" Display="false" Visible="true" AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" />
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="p_name" HeaderText="Name" AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" />     
    </Columns>
</MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

What I want to do is to insert the "**p_id**" for each checked rows in the database. But my loop is not working. Please suggest how can I achieve this.

code behind >>

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in rg_get_profession.Items)
{
    CheckBox chkbox = item.FindControl("TempCol1") as CheckBox;
    if(chkbox != null && chkbox.Checked)
    {
        string id = item.Cells[1].Text;
    }
}
```

While debugging the code, the execution does not go inside the if block though I checked multiple items in the rad grid check box. 
I tried doing ::

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in rg_get_profession.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chkbox = item.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
        if (chkbox != null && chkbox.Checked)
        {           
            string id_ = item.Cells[1].Text;            
        }
    }
```

Now when I put check mark in the check boxes, my execution goes inside the loop `if (chkbox != null && chkbox.Checked)` but I can not access the value of **p_id**.
`string id_ = item.Cells[1].Text;` is not giving the value of **p_id**.

How can I access the value of p_id which are check marked? Please suggest.

Comment: This id WebForms code, not MVC

Comment: thanks for the quick suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `item.Cells[1].Text;` to `item["p_id"].Text;`.
Code snippet to get the value of the datafield ::

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in rg_get_profession.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chkbox = item.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
        if (chkbox != null && chkbox.Checked)
        {           
            string id_ = item["p_id"].Text;            
        }
    }
```

I can get the value of the p_id which are checked mark.